# poor image quality

Tags: pixels

I have a photo that has been edited in google photos or the generic option in photos on an andriod now it looks like a weird design on my bare skin that is green and my bf swears its a tattoo and it's not how can I prove its not a tattoo but from the poor inage quality and messing with the editing options the photo looks like static or itrs fuzzy. We been arguing for 3 years can I send a file attachment to show someone and that way it can be shown that it is the photo?

Comment: That's not really how this site works. This is a public q and a site devoted to both helping individuals and providing resources for the community and posterity. Deducing an image artifact is on topic and finding the causes would be a good question, but you'd need to link the image publicly. It sounds like it may be a sensitive image. If so, then unfortunately this isn't the place to get 1:1 private help on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Have you not seen your boyfriend in three years? Is your boyfriend arguing that this one photo is real and all other photos are fakes? Is this serious or is it for some reason a joke your boyfriend is going on about that you're tired of? In any case, there *might* be a photo-related question in here somewhere, but as it is I'm having a really hard time figuring out what you mean. Maybe this is a situation where you can get advice at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Or maybe you can post the photo and we can deal with specifics of it?

Answer (score 2):

> it looks like a weird design on my bare skin that is green and my bf swears its a tattoo and it's not how can I prove its not a tattoo

Simple. Show him the area of skin. If it's not tatted or scarred, you win.

Answer (score -1):

Just show him the area of your body with the supposed tattoo.